# Retrieve a subset of a ViewModel from a RenderPartial on POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a ViewModel which contains a child ViewModel. In a strongly typed Viewed of the parent, I want to RenderPartial on the child, and have results persist following POST.
But the child fields are always null.

This should work, shouldn't it? I am fairly new to MVC, hopefully I'm missing something simple. Hopefully someone can point it out!

Thanks!

### Example

**ViewModels**

```
public class EggBoxViewModel
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public EggViewModel Egg { get; set; }
}

public class EggViewModel
{
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public bool IsBroken { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Demo()
{
    EggBoxViewModel eggBox = new EggBoxViewModel();
    eggBox.Brand = "HappyEggs";
    eggBox.Price = 3;

    EggViewModel egg = new EggViewModel();
    egg.Size = "Large";
    egg.IsBroken = false;

    eggBox.Egg = egg;

    return View(eggBox);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Demo(EggBoxViewModel eggBox)
{

    // here, eggBox.Egg is null
}
```

**Views
"Demo"**

```
@model MvcApplication1.ViewModels.EggBoxViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <h2>EggBox:</h2>
    <p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Brand)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Brand)
    </p>
    <p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
    </p>

    <p>
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_Egg", Model.Egg);}
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**"_Egg" (Partial)**

```
@model MvcApplication1.ViewModels.EggViewModel

<h2>Egg</h2>
<p>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Size)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Size)
</p>
<p>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsBroken)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsBroken)
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an Editor Template, in most cases they're better for rendering child objects or collections. In your Views\Shared folder create a new folder called EditorTemplates if you don't already have one. Add a new partial view called EggViewModel and use the same code as in your partial view. This is the bit of magic that renders and names all your fields correctly. It will also handle a collection of EggViewModels without a for each loop as the Editor template will automatically render all the items passed in a collection:

```
@model MvcApplication1.ViewModels.EggViewModel

<h2>Egg</h2>
<p>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Size)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Size)
</p>
<p>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsBroken)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsBroken)
</p>
```

Then in your Demo View use your new Editor Template instead of the partial:

```
<p>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Egg)
</p>
```

**Here** are the fields that are rendered:

[image: Rendered fields]

**In** the post back you can that the EggViewModel is now part of the EggBoxViewModel:

[image]

**Also** in the ModelState you can see that the Egg fields are prefixed with the property name used in the EggBoxViewModel which makes them a subset of EggBox.

[image]

**And**...the great thing is that if you want to have a collection of Eggs in your EggBox it's really easy...just make your Egg property on EggBoxViewModel a collection:

```
public class EggBoxViewModel
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EggViewModel> Eggs { get; set; }
}
```

**Add** a second egg:

```
public ActionResult Demo()
{
    EggBoxViewModel eggBox = new EggBoxViewModel();
    eggBox.Brand = "HappyEggs";
    eggBox.Price = 3;

    EggViewModel egg = new EggViewModel();
    egg.Size = "Large";
    egg.IsBroken = false;

    EggViewModel egg2 = new EggViewModel();
    egg2.Size = "Medium";
    egg2.IsBroken = false;

    eggBox.Eggs = new List<EggViewModel>();

    eggBox.Eggs.Add(egg);
    eggBox.Eggs.Add(egg2); 

    return View(eggBox);
}
```

**Change** your View to render x.Eggs instead of x.Egg:

```
<p>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Eggs)
</p>
```

**Then** on post back you'll see there are 2 Eggs posted back:

[image]

**The** field names have automatically been indexed and named to create a collection of Eggs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to change your partial view model to `EggBoxViewModel` so that the `Egg` object is exposed on the view. i.e:

```
@model MvcApplication1.ViewModels.EggBoxViewModel
<h2>
    Egg</h2>
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Egg.Size)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Egg.Size)
</p>
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Egg.IsBroken)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Egg.IsBroken)
</p>
```

thus, you'd call it from the main view as:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_Egg", Model);}
```

you should now see the `Egg` object in your model being returned in the `HttpPost` action.

[image: The object debug]

**[Update method 2]**

ok, really quick **edit**!! You can keep everything the same as initially and try this in your partial (i'm not 100% certain that this will work tho):

```
@model MvcApplication1.ViewModels.EggViewModel
<h2>
    Egg</h2>
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Size)
    @Html.Editor("Egg.Size", Model.Size)
</p>
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsBroken)
    @Html.CheckBox("Egg.IsBroken", Model.IsBroken)
</p>
```

here, I just use `@Html.Editor()` and input the required model name, rather than `@Html.EditorFor()`. Ok, gorra dash... train to 'cache' ;-)

Comment: Thanks Jim, that does indeed work. It doesn't seem quite right that other EggBox fields are then passed into the Egg partial view though. I would have thought that the whole point is to keep the partial concerned with just Egg? Then I could reuse it from elsewhere in a similar way.

Comment: kezmondo - actually, let me add a further alternative (tho this may not be until a little later as i'm leaving right now) that may allow the model to still be passed as purely the `Egg`

Comment: With "Update method 2", the values don't appear in the view initially (fields are blank). When I enter something and submit, the values do make it back to the controller though.